# about the rate of decay of a square summable sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I formulate the problem as follows:

Consider a positive sequence $\{a_{k}\}$ with $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k}^{2} < \infty.$ Can we get any estimation of the rate of decay of the sequence? One case is that $a_k$ may behave like $$a_k \sim (\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}})^{n}, ~~ n>1, $$
but i m not sure whether this is a necessary and sufficient condition. Can anyone give me some insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible answer to your question is "no" which can be made precise as follows. We'll say that the sequence $(b_n)_{n\geq1}$ *goes to zero infinitely slower than* $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ if both sequences tend to zero, and furthermore the sequence $\frac{|b_n|}{|a_n|}$ tends to $+\infty$, taking division by $0$ to mean $+\infty$.

Claim: Given any sequence $(a_n)$ in $\ell^2$, there is another sequence $(b_n)$ which goes to zero infinitely slower than $(a_n)$.

This will be shown true if we prove the following more general fact: Given any series with $\sum |c_n| < \infty$, there is a positive sequence $r_n \rightarrow \infty$ with $\sum r_n |c_n| <\infty$. Basically you can find a subsequence of integers $1\leq n_1 < n_2 < \cdots$ such that 
$$
\sum\limits_{n = n_k}^{\infty} |c_n| \leq \frac{1}{4^k} \; \forall k
$$

Then you can let $(r_n)_{n\geq 1} = (1,1,\ldots,1,2,2,\ldots,2,2^2,\ldots)$ chosen appropriately so that the tails of $\sum r_n |c_n|$ tend to zero.

Comment: This is a specially designed sequence. I wonder if it makes any difference if the sequence is further assumed to be non-increasing.

Answer (score 1):

The belonging to $l^2$ does not imply anything particular about the decaying rate of a sequence. Consider, for instance, that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and for any permutation $\sigma$ of $\mathbb{N}^+$ we have that the sequence given by:
$$ a_m = \frac{1}{\sigma(m)^{\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon}}$$
is square-summable.

Answer (score 0):

Stonger statements can be made if the sequence is nonincreasing. For simplicity I will work with summable sequences rather than square-summable. If $a_k$ is nonnegative, nonincreasing and $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k <\infty$$ then $a_k=o(1/k)$. In other words $\lim_{k\to\infty} k a_k = 0$.

On the other hand if $a_k$ is not assumed to be nonincreasing, what we can say is that $$\lim\inf k a_k = 0.$$
To prove this note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k>n} a_k = 0$. Therefore 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{2n} a_k = 0
$$ 
Now
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=n}^{2n} a_k
&\geq& 
n\inf\{a_k:n\leq k\leq 2n\}
\\
&=&
\frac{1}{2}\inf\{(2n)a_k:n\leq k\leq 2n\}
\\
&\geq &
\frac{1}{2}\inf\{k a_k: n\leq k\leq 2n\}
\\
&\geq &
\frac{1}{2}\inf\{ka_k:k\geq n\}.
\end{eqnarray*} 
If the sequence is nonincreasing then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=n}^{2n} a_k
&\geq& 
n\inf\{a_k:n\leq k\leq 2n\}
\geq \frac{1}{2}(2n)a_{2n}
\end{eqnarray*}
and similarly $(2n+1)a_{2n+1}$ can be shown to converge to $0$. Hence $a_k=o(1/k)$.